# Combining && with || in an if statement

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators, operator-precedence

I want to have a short if statement on one line that checks if condition A is met and then check if condition B is met, where both conditions are specific strings, but condition B has more than one valid option.

`if (cond_A === 'Bradley' && cond_B === 'April' || cond_B === 'May') { ... }`

This seems to work, but is it safe from giving unexpected/undesired results? Undesirable in this case would be interpreting just `cond_B === 'May'` as meeting the conditions. I guess I'm asking about order of operations: does `&&` have precedence over `||` ? I want the results to be the same as

```
if (cond_A === 'Bradley') { 
    if (cond_B === 'April' || cond_B === 'May') {
        ... 
    } 
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express conditions like this with brackets to force a particular order of evaluation:

```
A && B || C
(A && B) || C // How it is evaluated
A && (B || C) // Likely how you want it evaluated
```

The last form there is logically equivalent to your nested `if` approach. The need for the explicit ordering is because [`&&` has a slightly higher precedence than `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_precedence#table) in JavaScript.

You can also use a different tool:

```
A && ["1", "2", ...].includes(B)
```

Where you can check for things in a list via [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). This can express your intent more clearly, and scales better to larger lists of possible matches. For really large lists called really often you may even want to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).